# What is creating these gibberish files on my SD card?

Tags: file-management, files

I recently took my SD card out of my tablet, and put it into my laptop. However, there were gibberish files everywhere on the SD card. A few of them:

- In the Alarms folder, there were two files: `.fgbnm_uyivfqwpo.txt` and `.fgbnm_uyivfqwpo11.txt`. They both contained nothing but the stirng `rAa7m3BIebYuaNAiY2vVfbUMRvRym7Ym#1527480871`.
- In the DCIM folder, there were `.redghj_jklqwpo.hgk` and `.redghj_jklqwpo11.hgk`. They contained the same data as the files above.
- In the Documents folder, there were `iiy_pol_gthqwpo.mp3` and `iiy_pol_gthqwpo11.mp3`. They also contained the same data, and Windows Media Player encountered an error when playing it.
- In the Downloads folder, there were `.ertyui_opikqwpo.ziip`, `.ertyui_opikqwpo11.ziip`, `.y_androidqwpo.ziip`, and `.y_androidqwpo11.ziip`. If I opened them as a .zip file, I got "Please insert the last disk of the multi-disk set" on all 4 files.
- The Movies folder contained `dgdf_configqwpo.con` and `dgdf_configqwpo11.con`.
- The Ringtones folder contained `.ewsdf_oplkqwpo.kjl` and `.ewsdf_oplkqwpo11.kjl`.

The only things in common between all these files is the contents (`rAa7m3BIebYuaNAiY2vVfbUMRvRym7Ym#1527480871`) and the ending before the file extension (`wpo` and `wpo11`).

Searching the files found [this question](http://www.androidiani.com/forum/android-caf/549987-quattro-piccoli-strani-files.html) (it's in French!) that just says they can be deleted.

What app is creating these files? Whatever it is I want to remove it immediately.

Comment: Did u recently install the app clean master???

Comment: No. I've too many bad things about it to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer to your problem: These files come from installing applications from developers Cheetah Mobile. Delete the Cheetah Mobile app that you have installed and then delete these bogus files. Problem solved!

Comment: I had WhatsCall (Cheetah Mobile Cloud) installed, so I will see if uninstalling it fixes the problem.

Comment: I was worried too, googled and came to this thread. I uninstalled Photo Grid app developed by Cheetah then solved! Thanks Alfredo!

Comment: It actually helped! They didn't start showing up until a recent update. Perhaps it was a device or advertising ID, and the developers spammed it all over the SD card to stop it from getting deleted. 

Comment: @Zackary that's it on the nail, tbh. Shame really, I used to love these guys. How the mighty have fallen....